# variable predefinition, moving variable to earlier point

Tags: php, scope, php-5.3, goto

Ok, here's the deal where I'm really stuck.

I use my cms with design patterns.
Where's the last final output(in design template's main file: 'design.php'):

```
<div>{CONTENT_HEADER}</div>
<div style='float:left;width:25%'>{CONTENT_LEFT}</div>
<div style='float:left;width:50%'>{CONTENT_CENTER}</div>
<div style='float:left;width:25%'>{CONTENT_RIGHT}</div>
<div>{CONTENT_FOOTER}</div>
```

Where is **CONTENT_XXXX** is generater thought site modules:

```
ob_start("gz_handler");
<....... LOAD ALL THE HEADER MODULES .......>
$output0 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

ob_start("gz_handler");
<....... LOAD ALL THE LEFT SIDE MODULES .......>
$output1 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

ob_start("gz_handler");
<....... LOAD ALL THE CENTER SIDE MODULES .......>
$output2 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

ob_start("gz_handler");
<....... LOAD ALL THE RIGHT SIDE MODULES .......>
....
// That's I talk about, but this is just for static html, not variables
// Push to header finalizers to override default <title></title>
$header_finalizers_array['change_head_title_attr_to'] = $thread_data['topic_title'];
<....... END OF ALL THE RIGHT SIDE MODULES .......>
$output3 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

ob_start("gz_handler");
<....... LOAD ALL THE FOOTER MODULES .......>
$output5 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

define("CONTENT_HEADER", finalize_output($output0,$header_finalizers_array));
define("CONTENT_LEFT", finalize_output($output2,$left_finalizers_array));
define("CONTENT_CENTER", finalize_output($output3,$center_finalizers_array));
define("CONTENT_RIGHT", finalize_output($output4,$right_finalizers_array));
// No need finalizations, because there are no more parts, which call content changes
define("CONTENT_FOOTER", $output5);
```

All is ok in 95% of cases. But, there are some cases, where I need TO GET THE CONTENT OF VARIABLE(in left side modules) which ONLY will be defined in NEXT SIDE(ex. in right side modules)

With my code, I can define the site headers  in 'header modules', but then if I want that, I'm able to change it in ex. right side, because I'm able add to array the replace data requirement, which will be executed after all the side content will be generater to variables but BEFORE printing in to client browser.

All this could be done only with 1 line in function:

```
function finalize_output($output="",$fin_array=array()) {
   <...>
   $output = preg_replace("#<title>.*</title>#i", "<title>".$fin_array['change_head_title_attr_to']."</title>", $output, 1);
   <...>
}
```

---

### **Now about my problem.**

**How to do the same with VARIABLES:**

IN **LEFT SIDE** modules I have a sentence (PROBLEM: *$object* ):

```
if(isset($object)) {
  $best_product = sqlArray(sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE b='$object'"));
 <..All the rest code of BEST's product..>
}
```

IN **RIGHT SIDE** modules I have the sencence (PROBLEM: *$object* ):

```
<... Print LAST 10 PRODUCTS ***>
$res = sqlquery("SELECT * FROM tableA ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100);
while($data = sqlarray($res)) { <..PRINT PRODUCT INFO..> }

$new = rand(0,secured($_POST['user_input_new_products']));
for($i=1;$i<=$new;$i++) {
  $price_diff_old_new1 = change_products_to_sql('fish_$i', 19.99);
  $price_diff_old_new2 = push_product_to_sql('crab_$i', 16.99);
  if($i==$new) {
    $object = $price_diff_old_new1+$price_diff_old_new2;
  }
}
```

THIS IS JUST EXAMPLE CODE OF WHAT I NEED TO DO(so don't go to details), but **THE POINT IS THAT**, that *I need somehow to submit the variable to earlier point of source*:
One of solutions would be " **USE GOTO** ", but is it variable will be remebered.

I mean:

```
echo "JOB IS STARTED";
  LABEL HOME:
   <INCLUDED FILE : procuts.php >
      if(isset($object) && check_is_number($object)) {
       $a = $object;
      }
      if(isset($break_me) && $break_me) {
        GOTO FINAL;
      }
   <END OF INCLUDE>
   ...

 <INCLUDED FILE : upload.php >
    $object = 999;
    $break_me = true;
    GOTO HOME;
  <END OF INCLUDE>
}
 LABEL FINAL: 
echo "JOB IS DONE";
```

AND, is there are any other way to do this **WITHOUT GOTO**(if GOTO solution is possible(?)) ?

---

I personally thought that is not possible to code it, but since Php 5.3.0 it is possible, I become likely to be coded. Misfortunelly I'm not sure the company will use Php 5.3.0 on their servers, so I hope there is another solutions.

Also I'm still not sure even the *GOTO* will help there.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by LEFT SIDE modules and RIGHT SIDE modules.

Comment: The all website is an objects container, splitted into 3 parts for theme designers: LEFT SIDE PANELS(and their render code), RIGHT SIDE PANELS and CENTER PANELS.

This allows to change designer main site objects order, without any knowledge of Php.

Answer (score 1):

**I suggest rethinking your architecture.**

No offense, but the code looks rather messy to me.

To point out a few things:

- you said you use [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern), but the only pattern seems to be a [Template View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/templateView.html). You don't seem to be using [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), nor a [Two-Step View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/twoStepView.html), which would both be appropriate in your case.
- is there any particular reason why you are not using [OOP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)? It's not that procedural coding is a bad thing, but proper [encapsulation of things that conceptually go together](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) and [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) will make your app much more maintainable.
- your variable names are not meaningful. An `$output0` really tells you nothing about what is inside. Why does `$object` hold a number? The same is true for your function names: `push_to_sql()` and `change_to_sql()` sound alike. I guess one means *insert* and one means *update*, but the semantics could be much clearer.
- Why are you assigning the [variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) holding your content-blocks to [constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)? That step is completely superfluous as you can use the variables in your template view as well.

Now, I understand you used example code in your question's description, so bear with me if I addressed points not applicable to your production code. But still, the simple fact that your modules cannot be rearranged without affecting the other indicates a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Modules should be self-contained.

But let's get to your issue now.

You say you need to submit the variable to an earlier point in the source. I do not understand the example code enough to figure out why. But if you have to keep your <s>[Big Ball of Mud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud)</s>current architecture, you could [refactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refactor) all the code that will be shared among modules into a separate function. Then preload all required data and inject it into the functions rendering the content-blocks. This way, you should be able to push them around as wanted.

If you don't have to keep your current architecture, do yourself a favor and have a look at the patterns linked above. Most [PHP frameworks](http://www.phpframeworks.com/) utilize them and you might want to consider migrating your app onto one. To further improve your code, have a look at these [QA tools](http://phpqatools.org/) and check out these sites:

- http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/
- http://www.fluffycat.com/PHP-Design-Patterns/
- http://sourcemaking.com/design%5Fpatterns